# How do I proxy to my Express/MongoDB api from a React application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, proxy

I am having difficulty understanding why the API I created in MongoDB and Express throws `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

I have created a simple app with `create-react-app` and decided to add my own back end with Node, Express and MongDB.

The repo is here:

https://github.com/RyanPayso13/flightscheduler

The app (front and back end) can be started with `npm run dev`.

I hope someone can help me as this is very frustrating.  Am new to Node, Express and MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good. Probably just need the proxy scrypt. Put this in the **package.json** of the client-side, right after the scripts.

```
  "scripts": {
    ...
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

Your server might not be on port 5000, so will have to adjust to whatever you use.

Comment: I thought this would be take care of in the setupProxy.js file configuration?